# Hibernate/JPA lock OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

I've got a problem setting the lock mode on an object.

Here is the code :

```
MyObject a = myQuery.getSingleResult();
logger.info(entityManager.getLockMode(a));
entityManager.lock(a, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
logger.info(entityManager.getLockMode(a));
```

The result is :

```
OPTIMISTIC
OPTIMISTIC
```

My object A contains a list of objects B. I would like to increment A whenever a B is modified, here is why I use the Force increment feature.

But obviously it's not working at all. Some help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of searching, I was using Hibernate 3.6.10.Final version which has this superb bug :
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5222

> upgrade from READ to OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT fails
>
> Fix Version/s: 4.0.0.CR7

In short, by default the lock is set to READ which has a higher priority than OPTIMISTIC OR OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT so you can't change it.

So I upgraded to 4.2.0.Final and everything went ok